# Using GitSharp to PUSH changes

Tags: git, gitsharp

How can [GitSharp](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp) (Git for .NET and Mono) be used to PUSH changes changes to a remote server over SSH?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, yes, the latest [GitSharp 0.3 release](http://www.eqqon.com/index.php/GitSharp/v0.3.0) (June 2010) includes:

> bug fixes in the transport code (**pushing** / fetching via http or **ssh**)

The [GitSharp README.txt](https://github.com/jagregory/GitSharp) does have:

> #### Object transport
>
> - Fetch via ssh, git, http and bundles.
> - Push via ssh, git. Git# does not yet deltify
>     the pushed packs so they may be a lot larger than C Git packs.

---

You will find an example of such a push (over ssh) in [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/gitsharp/browse_thread/thread/c13f76b7708197ea/f78b0916b15a0525?lnk=gst&q=ssh#f78b0916b15a0525):

```
Repository repository = new Repository(@"\path\to\my_repos");
repository.Index.Add(@"\path\to\my_file");

Commit commited = repository.Commit("Testing fromGitC#", new Author("Author", "...@aCompany.com"));

if(commited.IsValid) {
    PushCommand pushCommand = new PushCommand {
        RefSpecs = new List<RefSpec> {
           new RefSpec("HEAD", "refs/for/master")
        },
        Force = true,
        Repository = repository
    };
    pushCommand.AddAll();
    pushCommand.Execute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  Two concerns of mine with GitSharp to PUSH at this point 1) It does not yet 'deltify' 2) The SSH library it uses is the v1 library (deprecated) http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/seclib/download.qpx

Comment: @ccook: I completely agree. I am not sure about the degree of activity of that GitSharp project.

Comment: I accepted this, as it *should* work once things with SSH Transport are resolved...  Note that the alternative, NGIT, also has SSH problems.

Answer (score 2):

GitSharp is based upon a manual port of JGit from Java to C#.  There is another project does this semi-automatically (with the purpose of being added to MonoDevelop)

http://foodformonkeys.blogspot.com/2010/10/ngit.html

https://github.com/slluis/ngit

> ### ABOUT NGIT
>
> NGit is a port of JGit [1] to C#. This
>   port is generated semi-automatically
>   using Sharpen [2], a Java-to-C#
>   conversion utility.
>
> NGit provides all functionality
>   implemented by JGit, including all
>   repository manipulation primitives and
>   transport protocols. SSH support is
>   provided by a port of jsch [3],
>   included in the project.
>
> The project is composed by 4
>   libraries:
>   - NGit: The git library.
>   - NGit.Test: Unit tests for NGit
>   - NSch: The port of jsch.
>   - Sharpen: Some support classes required by the above libraries.